# Genes of the electron transport chain

Tags: dna, proteins

Where are the genes of proteins that make the electron transport chain of mitochondria?(are they in in the nucleus or they are in the dna of the mitochondria itself?) Thanks for this answering system by the way

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please take the Tour and learn about this site. You are expected to do some research before posting, especially for Homework questions. You can easily find the answer to this question by an internet search.  Do this, and then come back if there are particular problems that remain unresolved.

Comment: Dear David thanks for your welcoming so much.Honestly I am a student as you guessed but this one was not a school project.It's really nice of you pushing the student's to find the answer themself , instead of just asking them .but I did a search on the web and couldn't find what i wanted since I am not studying in english-there was also nothing on the web in my native language Persian.So if you can help me with the keywords that I have to search to find my answer,I will be really thankful.Have a nice time.

Comment: @ArmanJalali Hi, the question can be easily resolved if you try to find articles speaking about each of the four subunits of the transport chain individually. For instance, for the first subunit (NADH oxidoreductase) you can find your answer in the abstract of [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/hmg/article/7/10/1573/635023)   Good luck with the rest!

Comment: The Wikipedia page on [Mitochondrial DNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrial_DNA) is an easy first stop. Comes up on the first page of a Google search. You need to search in English, I'm afraid. Your browser should allow you to switch search languages. Firefox does, for sure.

Comment: Actually the article is available in Farsi: https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/دی%E2%80%8Cان%E2%80%8Cای_میتوکندریایی